# How to read column from data table and display as check box format in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am developing a C# windows application. I am trying to read excel file and to display column name as check box entity. I used the following code but can't display anything in the DataGridView.

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
 {
 using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
 {
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
 cmd.Connection = con;
 con.Open();
oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
oda.Fill(dt);
con.Close();
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count;i++)
 {
 DataColumn dc = dt.Columns[i];
 CheckBox Ckb = new CheckBox();
 Ckb.Name = dc.ToString();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Columns[i].ToString();
}
}
}
```

I want the out put to look like the following :
[image: screenoutput]

Thanks

Comment: There is link with explanation how to add text to checkbox column : http://www.murrayhilltech.com/articles/articles.aspx?key=7 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to populate the DataGrid in a For Loop?

Before the For loop you can try this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
Oda.Fill(ds, "Table");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table"];
```

Comment: I want to populate the DataGrid using a for loop because the number of columns is not fixed , it depends up on the file imported by the user , the file may have 5 columns or 6 columns or 8 , the number of columns is differ time to time .

Comment: I edited the answer. The number of collums does not matter. The `DataSet` will store the table as is.

Comment: you SELECT * statement will get all the tables contents. collums and rows.

Comment: It is throwing  an error 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter' does not contain a definition for 'Tables' and no extension method 'Tables' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter' could be found

Comment: It must be `ds.Tables["Table"];` ill edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you . It's working .... but I want to display check boxes equal to number of columns as the first column on Data Grid view and the name of the check boxes should be the name of columns . How can I do that? can you help me out please .

Comment: Okay im glad. Please accept the answer if it helped you. I do not quite understand what you saying, you might want to ask another question specific to what you want to achieve then i will try and help you.

Comment: I am trying to do is that , populate the DataGridView  from the database; when the form is loaded only column names of the record will be display in DataGrid view and add check box column to the DATAGridView at the first column , then when the user click a button named ' Checkall '   All check box's in grid view will be set as checked and store the values of all selected rows into a list .

Comment: You want to change the rows of a datagridview into check boxes?

Comment: I think the bust way to do that is to design a Yes or no collum and not try do  it with code.